# Add anchored shapes in the margin area in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, drawing, margins, shapes

I need to rewrite a resume in PDF to Word. The section headers are marked with additional rectangles in the margin area, like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntWF9.png]

How would I do that in MS Word, in the .docx format? I found some tutorials, but they either move the whole line to the margin (using negative offset), which means that the actual title won't start exactly at the margin. I also tried drawing freehand shapes, but they need to be manually centered on lines and repositioned if the header changes position.

Answer (score 2):

Tables are a great way to position text in a Word document. Below I simulated what you gave as an example.

This table is 2 x 6 with the boarders turned off and fill used to give the color bars in the designated cells.

[image]

This is what it looks like in print preview.

[image]

You will have to experiment with it to get it the way you want. If you prefer, you can add shapes to the cells instead of fill color. Below just uses shapes placed in those cells, but the table gives structure to the text of the document.

[image]